# What is the number of linearly independent solutions of a set of vectors taken from identity matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have a set of $3$ vectors $X = (1,0,0)$, $Y = (0,1,0)$ and $Z = (0,0,1)$ then these all form a linearly independent set of vectors, so $K(X)+P(Y)+Q(Z) = 0$, so we get $K=P=Q=0$, but my confusion is what is the number of independent solutions to this, since rank of matrix formed from these vectors will be $3$ and according to the formula the number of independent solutions = number of unknowns - rank of matrix, then we get the number of independent solutions $= 0$, so how can it be $0$ here?

Comment: By number of independent solutions if you mean nullity then 0 is correct.

Comment: Keep in mind these vectors put into a matrix give you the identity function from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R^3$.  As such it is one-to-one and onto, so only one point can map to any given point, in particular only one point can map to zero.

Comment: I am not getting what is the difference between the no of linearly dependent solutions and linearly independent solutions